# Vbscript to do a loop until a string is found

Tags: windows, networking, vbscript, wmi

I apologize if this is a repetition but I did not find suitable help so far.

What I am trying to accomplish is to list all network adapters of a computer that have a certain value (2 in NetConnectionStatus in WMI). And then, from this list of network adapters names, I want to check if some of them contains a string while not containing another.

In my example I do not wan to evaluate the string if the string contains "Juniper". 
However if the string contains "4G" or "HSPA" or "Mobile" for example, I want to echo "Mobile" otherwise "Not Mobile"

So basically here is my first try (but this gives me an infinite loop...)

Thanks a lot for your help !

```
Set oWsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   

Set oWshSysEnv = oWsh.Environment("PROCESS")   

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")   

Set colItems = GetObject("WinMgmts:root/cimv2").ExecQuery("select Name from Win32_NetworkAdapter where (NetConnectionStatus = 2)")   

Dim commentStr

For Each objItem In colItems      

commentStr = ObjItem.Name

Do While not InStr(1, commentStr, "Juniper") > 0

If InStr(1, commentStr, "4G") > 0 then

wscript.echo "Mobile"

Else

wscript.echo "Not Mobile"

End If

Loop

Next
```

Comment: What is the point of the `Do While` loop? You just need `If` statement to check first using `InStr()` for `Juniper` then use the `Else` to check the other conditions using a nested `If` statement. The loop isn't doing anything, in fact, it has the potential to run infinitely which isn't good.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart . Actually the issue is that if a computer is connected with a mobile network card, it will always return 2 values. Juniper and another one. And this is just the second one that I want to evaluate. So I do a If Juniper do nothing Else do something it will not work as it will matches both conditions

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get what I wanted using various If as @lankymart suggested:

```
Set oWsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   

Set oWshSysEnv = oWsh.Environment("PROCESS")   

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")   

Set colItems = GetObject("WinMgmts:root/cimv2").ExecQuery("select Name from Win32_NetworkAdapter where (NetConnectionStatus = 2)")   



Dim commentStr

Dim mobile

Dim Juniper



For Each objItem In colItems      

commentStr = ObjItem.Name



If InStr(1, commentStr, "Juniper") > 0 then

Juniper=1

End If

If InStr(1, commentStr, "Mobile") > 0 then

Mobile=1

End If

If InStr(1, commentStr, "HSPA") > 0 then

Mobile=1

End If


Next


If Juniper=1 And Mobile=1 then

wscript.echo "Mobile"

Else

wscript.echo "Not Mobile"

End If
```